# Angular List HttpClient

Tags: angular, list, components, httpclient

I have create a list of member in my component(MemberComponent), i use a MemberService with an HttpClient to extract data.

There is my MemberService :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MemberService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMembers(): Observable<IMember[]> {
    return this.http.get<IMember[]>('http://localhost:50867/api/Member');
  }

  getMember(memberId) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:50867/api/Member/' + memberId);
  }
}
```

When I display this data in my MemberComponent.html, that perform.

There is my MemberComponent.ts :

```
export class MemberComponent implements OnInit {

  public members = [];

  constructor(private _memberService: MemberService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this._memberService.getMembers()
      .subscribe(data => this.members = data);
  }
```

And this is my MemberComponent.html :

```
<h2>Members list</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let member of members">
    <a routerLink="/details/{{member.idUser}}">{{ member.username }}</a>

    <ul>
      <li>{{ member.emailUser }}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So you can see in my Html the `<a routerLink ...>` , when i click on it it open my DetailComponent, in this component i try to display more informations of the member but i don't have any idea how to do that :/

There is my DetailComponent :

```
<h1>{{ members.name }}</h1>

<ul>
  <li><strong>wow:</strong> {{ members.username }}</li>
  <li><strong>Email:</strong> {{ members.email }}</li>
  <li><strong>Phone:</strong> {{ members.phone }}</li>
</ul>
```

Can you help me thank's in advance ;)

Comment: You have to retrieve your member information in your DetailComponent. You can do that by using your `getMember` function in your DetailComponent.

Comment: Thank's that perform now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the root which display detail page in route module. 
Such as;

```
 { path: 'details/:id', component: DetailComponent },
```

in detail component ts.

```
    constructor(
            .....
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
private _memberService: MemberService) {
```

You need to inject ActivatedRoute in your component.

Define memberId in ts file,

You can get Id in Init function.

```
if (this.route.snapshot.params.id) {
            this.memberId= this.route.snapshot.params.id;
        }
```

Then call your service.

```
 this._memberService.getMember(this.memberId)
      .subscribe(data => this.member = data);
```

Detail html should be

```
<h1>{{ member.name }}</h1>

<ul>
  <li><strong>wow:</strong> {{ member.username }}</li>
  <li><strong>Email:</strong> {{ member.email }}</li>
  <li><strong>Phone:</strong> {{ member.phone }}</li>
</ul>
```